# EF Core 6 - property custom value based on data from other tables

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there any option to defined property value based on custom select statement from another table? I am making additional software to existing ERP system, so database is not mine.

I have a `Document` model that has `SettledStatus`. I'm using Dapper now, so it's easy to retrieve data, but Dapper is a pain when it comes to inserting/updating especially when original column names are terrible.

**Example SQL**

```sql
select 
case when sum(Payment.SettledAmount) = 0 then 'N' 
when (Document.Gross - sum(Payment.SettledAmount)) > 0 then 'C' 
when (Document.Gross - sum(Payment.SettledAmount)) = 0 then 'R' 
else 'N' end 
from Payments 
where Payment.DocumentId = Document.Id 
group by Payment.DocumentId
```

This property would be only selectable, it should be skipped on inserting/updating, because there is no `SettledStatus` in `Documents` table.

Am I able to achieve this with EF Core 6?

#EDIT

**My suggestion**

```cs
    public class Document
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string SettledStatus { get; set; }
        public decimal Gross { get; set; }

        private List<Payments> _payments;
        public List<Payments> Payments 
        { 
            get { return _payments; } 
            set
            {
                _payments = value;
                if (_payments.Sum(x => x.SettledAmount) == 0)
                    SettledStatus = "N";
                else if (Gross - _payments.Sum(x => x.SettledAmount) > 0)
                    SettledStatus = "C";
                else if (Gross - _payments.Sum(x => x.SettledAmount) == 0)
                    SettledStatus = "R";
                else
                    SettledStatus = "N";
            }
        }
    }

    public class Payments
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int DocumentId { get; set; }
        public decimal SettledAmount { get; set; }
        public Document Document { get; set; }
    }
```

In context I would do

```cs
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasMany(s => s.Payments).WithOne(s => s.Document);
   }
```

Comment: Start from showing model and how do you plan to query such property.

Comment: That is my question actually. How should I query such property? EF Core has no raw quering without entity and I want it to do automaticaly.

Comment: Via `Select` you can. Via `Include` or you want this property to load automatically, It is quite problematically.

Comment: I've edited my question. Is it going to work that way?

Comment: For which purpose you need this property in Model class? Maybe just create another DTO class and project everything what is needed? Anyway we can do that even with  `Document` class, but entity will be detached from `ChangeTracker`.

Comment: I like to keep it simple, in one model, setup with attributes what should be use to insert/update and what is just readonly. If I use DTO, how it should look and how it is going to help?

Comment: *I like to keep it simple, in one model*, well I have opposite advice,  do not pollute model with not related to database model information. DTO is for sending result to the client and it may contain a lot of another calculated information.

Comment: Well, you might be right. I've never come across so much difference between database table and model in code. The main reason is, that this is not my database and I have to submit to the database, but at the same time I want to make my life easier... And after that I am going to be rich 

Answer (score 1):

I propose to change your class to the following:

```cs
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public decimal Gross { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string SettledStatus { get; set; }

    public List<Payments> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

And write the following helper method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<Document> GetDocuments(DbContext context)
{
    return context.Set<Document>().Select(d => new Document
    {
        Id = d.Id,
        Number = d.Number,
        Grass = d.Grass,
        Payments = d.Payments,

        SettledStatus = 
            (from p in d.Payments
            group p by p.DocumentId into g
            let sum = g.Sum(x => x.SettledAmount)
            select sum == 0 ? "N" : 
                    d.Gross - sum > 0 ? "C" :
                    d.Gross - sum == 0 ? "R" :
                    "N"
            ).Single();
    })
}
```

Then you can use this method in queries and field `SettledStatus` will be initialised.

```cs
var result = GetDocuments(context)
   .Where(d => d.Id == documentId)
   .ToList();
```