# Entity Framework using generic fields to point to specific table

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with Entity Framework Core (6.0.7) on a legacy database, that isn't under my control, so I can't change any of the database structure unfortunately.

The database structure that I've inherited has quite a few tables in the following format. (this isn't the actual structure, I've simplified it for this question)

```
id          int (pk)
name        varchar
item_model  varchar
item_id     int
...
```

It's probably irrelevant but I'm using `MySQL`.

Where the `item_model` contains the name of a table, and the `item_id` contains the id of the primary key for that table. So the `item_id` can point to many different tables.

Although I don't like this pattern, it is used throughout the DB, and in some cases, with only one or two distinct item_models.

Some example data might be

```
id  name    item_model   item_id
1   Item1   ships        5
2   Item2   cruises      2
3   Item3   ships        3
...
```

I would prefer the table to look like... as I would then be able to define the foreign keys correctly, and allow the navigation field to work correctly.

```
id  name    ship_id    cruise_id
1   Item1   5          null
2   Item2   null       2
3   Item3   3          null
...
```

But as I mentioned before, I can't change the DB structure

How can I tell EF that if `item_model`=`ships` that the `item_id` refers to a `ship_ip` on the `ships` table?

I was thinking of creating a virtual field on the model which has either a c# or SQL case statement on it, but I can't see how I can do this. i.e. something like `case when item_model='ships' then item_id else null end as ship_id`

I guess the bottom line is that I want to keep the logic as simple as possible for anybody utilising the model/repository, and just being able to specify `tab.Cruises.CruiseLaunchDate` rather that having to add logic to each query in the repository.

ps. I'm relatively new to EF, so please forgive me if I've missed something obvious.

Comment: You have missed classes and examples of usage. Virtual fields will not help. For which purpose you have used EF? Reading data or for CRUD?

Comment: I didn't think that classes/examples would help, as this is more or a conceptual question that I haven't implemented yet, I've just used the EF classes that were generated using db-first, so there's nothing really specific to my question in there. Also I noticed that you removed the tag for EF, I added this because I thought it might be relevant to all versions of EF (not just core).

Comment: And sorry, the use of EF was decided by our 'executive' team, I prefer using raw SQL, but we have some people in the team that don't understand pure SQL. We're using it for CRUD on ASP.Net

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73238736/10646316), I have enriched class with property which can be queryable. You can do the same for `Cruises` property. Minus such classes are not tracked.

Comment: Also it is possible to create property which can be used in queries, but it needs third party extensions, which corrects expression tree. That's why I request usage samples.